# Answers of newbie learners. Examples from literature

Tags: discussion, new-users

I'm newbie in English. I have no problem with most of my questions at my level, I have no need to ask about. And I'm active user of literature examples database. Examples from this base really very useful for me as a learner.

And I think so.. These examples are useful for me. May be these examples will be useful for some another people? Why not. And I added many examples as an answer to some questions. At my level I can't explain with theory of English language, and hope that some people will give alternative answers, and different answers together will give us synergistic effect.

I think this is good practice for learning.

But, I faced that some experienced users of this site criticize me for my answers with examples from literature. I don't think (as a learner) that many examples are bad, but maybe this is opinion of community, and if so - I will stop to publish my answers with examples.

Some links to questions with my answers:

[On using "in it" in a sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232945/on-using-in-it-in-a-sentence/232952#232952)

[Is it correct to say before he come or before he came](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232940/is-it-correct-to-say-before-he-come-or-before-he-came/232943#232943)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand what you are trying to mean. First of all, you lack the very important "be verbs". "This examples useful for me."--> "**These** examples **are** useful for me"  "And I add many examples as an answer to some questions."  "And I **added** many examples as an answer to some questions." Yeah of course as a learner same with you from Asia, I make some mistakes quite often, but I am very sorry to say your sentence as a whole is very hard to read. May be you'd better get some not-free English class somewhere, isn't it possible?

Comment: A good thing to do is to tag (or provide the links to) the answers you are talking about here in the Meta question.

Comment: Kentaro Donates For Monica, thank you! I have not-free class as well. I think my progress with "be verb" will be in some time. At first this is a practice. And feedback from people like you! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem strange to provide examples of the usage but no explanation of the usage. In our model, we stress providing explanations with answers. You have a slightly different issue from the usual one. Often, users will simply provide the "right" answer without explanation. See [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/submitting-answers-that-merely-answer-the-question)

You're doing something kind of similar. You're implying a “right” answer through examples. It's great to provide examples. However, we first request that you provide a proper explanation.

As an aside, the one main problem that comes to my mind with basing your answer on examples is that having a number of examples of a usage does not necessarily make it "right". The examples could be of something different (irrelevant), archaic, or even ungrammatical/"non-standard" (e.g. dialogue between two rural folks).  You should take extra care if you’re not as knowledgeable or confident about a usage. You could be inadvertently misleading or misinforming the OP.

Comment: Thank you <i>Em.</i>, I totally agree with this warning! I try to find form that can lead risk of misinforming the OP as low as it can. I understand that examples from books can be not acceptable for more strict language situation, and maybe just warning the OP about that will be enough?

Comment: I can see that exists two big different language categories, strict (rules and so on), and more flexible language for art expression something. For me and my purposes is more interesting second form. And I'm trying to answer to question that has topic near to second form and will give attention to risk of nonstandard language using by examples from books to prevent of misleading of the OP. And I'll keep hope that maybe another answers with my answer together will gives more wide picture to the OP. My answers are not pretend on exclusive role. Thank you!

Comment: @sayfriend I am very sorry to say that your English is from the bottom of the rule is against it. For instance, I don't understand the first part of your last comment, "I can see that exists two big different language categories, strict (rules and so on), and more flexible language for art expression something.". If it is written as "I can see that **big difference** exists **between** different languages, if they are strict or not ( such as rules and so on )...I would have understood you more correctly.

Comment: @sayfriend I am really sorry to say like this. You have some issue on using English verbs and I hope you polish that part then I would understand you better. Thank you anyway^^.

Comment: Kentaro Donates For Monica, that's all right! (Sure not with my verbs!). I'm really thankful for your feedback! It is always value for me.