# Why was my answer removed without a reason?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, I answered a question on https://ell.stackexchange.com/, however, today when I look at my answer it says it has been removed by this user https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/snailcar

I would like to know why my answer was removed, as I believe it answered the question when no-one else had.

Comment: [Submitting answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/submitting-answers-that-merely-answer-the-question) has some community discussion about brief answers that might be helpful.

Comment: The answers offered by others seem sufficiently clear as to what they are and the reasoning behind them. Your *answer* wasn't so much an "improvement" over existing answers than it was an attempt to comment on an existing answer. [Your ability to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342195/282094) has been explained previously, circumventing the privilege needed to comment by phrasing it as an incomplete answer is also explained. Nothing has happened "without a reason".

Comment: I don’t think this question should be down-voted, even though it was initially posted on the wrong meta. Posting here is exactly what someone should do when they have a question like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/236068/can-i-use-you-can-rather-than-could-you-in-restaurants/236126#236126) was entirely in support of another existing answer. It read:

> No, you can't
>
> As Colin mentioned, it's considered rude.

Subsequent answers need to add additional information to be retained. Because of this, your answer was removed. If you agree with an existing answer you can upvote it (once you have 15 reputation). Please don't add agreement with existing answers as a new answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the original question was "Can I say x", none of the answers actually said 'yes' or 'no' or attempted to answer the original, they gave extensive information about the phrasing and as to why it's considered rude, but I did not see an actual answer. Therefore I believed my answer was completely appropriate to post

Comment: Every answer there explains the form, which is valid for many purposes and discourages its use in that specific situation because it's rude. You *can* absolutely use that form... it's just rude. So the answer is "It's not recommended because it's rude" and I believe the existing answers there explain that just fine. If you feel they could use improvement, the best solution is to submit an edit suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't I receive an explanation when the post is deleted?

Comment: @Cherona Nope. We don't typically draw attention when users' posts are deleted. If a moderator wishes, they can leave a comment but it's not necessary or required.